# Use layout as html express js

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm new to NodeJs and have created one HTML page with Header and Footer. Now I want to use it as Master page of other HTML pages. I don't want to use Jade. Can I define and use layout as HTML in NodeJs. I'm using ExpressJS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a templating engine. Jade (now named Pug) is one such, but there are loads more.

[Here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)'s some documentation on the express website on templating engines.

[Here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki#template-engines)'s a list of templating engines on their own wiki.